# help: mongodb find simple test vs mssql select test

Tags: mongodb

Im trying to see if mongodb is a fit for us. So i have with simple test:

Num of rows: 1.24 mil
Cols: 20

### MSSQL:

```
select date,sum(revenue) from sales group by date
```

### Results

Returned in 1sec

### MongoDB

```
$keys = array("date"=>1);

    $initial = array("rev" => 0);

    $reduce = "function (obj, prev) { prev.rev += obj.revenue; }";

    return $collection->group($keys, $initial, $reduce);
```

### Results

Script timed out

--

What am i doing wrong??

Surely mongodb can do better than this?

If mongodb can win this test my next test is on a 30mil table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation

*before* using Map-Reduce?

Comment: i thought I was doing that, can you give me more explain more?